# How to get divs side-by-side

Tags: css, layout, html

I have code generating children div's based on N nodes in a collection, could be one or more nodes, so the resulting html is like this:

```
<div class='parent_div'>
<div class ='child_div'></div>
<div class ='child_div'></div>
</div>

<div class='parent_div'>
<div class ='child_div'></div>
<div class ='child_div'></div>
<div class ='child_div'></div>
</div>
```

What would the CSS look like to make all the children nodes be side by side?

Here is a more robust example in jsFiddler that is much closer to what is really going on.  I am NOT able to get it to work in Firefox or IE:

http://jsfiddle.net/scarleton/GqjtC/10/

Part of what I am seeking help on here is how best to get the columns spaced correctly.  Should I use percentage or actual pixels?  I don't know, I am open to either, just need some advice.

Comment: Could you just apply the float:left CSS style to the all child_div's?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `float:left` or `display:inline-block`

float

```
.child_div{
   float: left;
}
.parent_div{
    clear:both;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f3BtH/1/)

inline-block

```
.child_div{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f3BtH/)

Note

- White spaces take up space(except at the beginning or end of block level elements), use float to overcome this, or remove the spaces
- The dimension of Floated elements do not affect the parent unless there is a sibling to clear the float
- Border and padding makeup extra width use [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing): border-box  to overcome this

inline block - http://jsfiddle.net/GqjtC/8/

float - http://jsfiddle.net/GqjtC/9/

Comment: Ok, I am trying the the whole 'display: inline-block' and I cannot figure out how to get the div's to be equal width, I am trying two different approaches, both result in the last div on the next line: http://jsfiddle.net/GqjtC/3/

Comment: I just did, your stuff works in Opera, but not in Firefox or IE.  The issue is that I want all the children to be spaced equally and on the same line.  In both Firefox both techniques have the last column of 3 and 5 rapping to the next line.  In IE, the float works.

Comment: Part of what I am seeking help on here is how best to get the columns spaced correctly.  Should I use percentage or actual pixels?  I don't know, I am open to either, just need some advice.

Comment: @SamCarleton I don't know why it doesn't work with IE but firefox requires the `-moz-` prefix http://jsfiddle.net/GqjtC/13/

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
.child_div {
    float: left
}
```

A few points I was thinking about:

- Instead of just floating the child_div left, I would consider making a more contextual selector such as:

  ```
  .parent_div > div {
      float: left;
  }
  ```

  This basically says that the `div`s that are immediate children of `.parent_div` will be floated.
- Floating has drawbacks: the parent container does not preserve the height of the children if all children are floated. So if `.parent_div` is supposed to be a bordered box surrounding the children, you may need additional CSS or markup.
- `display: inline-block` has drawbacks: you may run into cross-browser compatibility issues.

If there are a dynamic number of columns, setting the widths might get tricky. Not sure if this is applicable to you, but I would recommend looking into a grid system, such as [960.gs](http://www.960.gs). Good luck!

Comment: ah, thanks Jon. I'll borrow one of the .'s from your ellipses :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want them *all* in a line, you would have to know the width of each one. If you just want them to continuously loop like text normally does, there are a couple of different solutions.

### Option 1

You can treat them like list items in a `ul` and have this for your css:

```
.parent_div .child_div {
  ...
  display: inline;
}
```

### Option 2

You can float each `div` to the left or the right, depending on which side you want them to come from:

```
.parent_div .child_div .from_right {
  ...
  float: right;
}

.parent_div .child_div .from_left {
  ...
  float: left;
}
```

### Option 3

Like I was saying above, you need to know the width of each `div` to be able to make them all appear in a single line on the screen. If you don't know how many elements there will be, you can consider making a `table` (*gasp!*) to hold them instead of using `divs`, like so:

```
<table class="data">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Just make sure everything is in the same `tr`. Otherwise, the lines will wrap. The advantage of this is you can loop your creation script to make a certain, flexible number of elements appear in a row without even having to touch your css.

Answer (score 1):

Add to the child-div this:

```
.child_div{
   ...
   float: left;
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

What [Razvan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961487/razvan) and [Tuanderful](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280909/tuanderful) said, but you will need to also set widths in there somewhere too - whether it is just the `.parent_div`, or both the `.parent_div` and `.child_div`.

Good luck!

Comment: There isn't a *need* to set the widths, it just helps if you want consistency.

Comment: Exactly, but the OP hasn't marked one as the correct answer, so I just wanted to continue helping in case this was a required fix (as the info given was pretty vague).